# pytables groups and weak references

Tags: python, pytables

I recently encountered an error accessing groups in a reasonably large (~500MB) hdf5 file. A line similar to this

```
stuff = table.root._v_groups.values()[1]._v_groups.values()[2]
```

caused `ProxyDict` to raise an exception "the container object does no longer exist" (meaning it no longer has a weak reference to its internal container).

Splitting the above up into

```
stuff1 = table.root._v_groups.values()[1]
stuff2 = stuff1._v_groups.values()[2]
```

works fine.

I suspect this has something to do with pytables' cache and / or the use of weak references, but was unable to identify exactly what is was. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(I also suspect a better thing to do would have been

```
stuff = getattr(getattr(table.root, 'group1'), 'subgroup2')
```

but the originally code was passing indices around)

Comment: Are you trying recursively get group names (descending the Group hierarchy)? If so, have you looked at the `walk_groups()` File method? It is much easier than your code above, and will work from any starting group (with the `where=` parameter) and recursively descend all groups levels. I can provide an example if you need one.

Comment: No it's even more basic than that. I was debugging a function that was attempting to access a group given indices `(i,j)` that meant "the jth child of the ith child of the root group". It's silly to try to do this with indices when you can just do `getattr(table.root, 'a/b')` and the function has been rewritten. I was more curious about why it's not possible to chain access to `._v_groups` in the first snippet.

Comment: Interesting situation. If you know the names a priori (and the groups exist), you can use natural naming to get them like this: `stuff = table.root.group1.subgroup2` or with `stuff = table.get_node('/group1/subgroup2')`.  Getting "the jth child of the ith child of the root group" is not something I've ever had to do. I'm usually looking for a group or dataset(table) by name, so use `walk_nodes(), walk_groups(), iter_nodes() or list_nodes()` depending on my needs: 1) a recursive search (or not), and 2) return an iterator vs a list.

Comment: Also, as an aside, I am not found of naming my File object "table" -- it's too confusing when you also have table objects (IMHO) :) I like to use h5f, because then I always know it's my HDF5 File.

Comment: Yeah it's odd, my guess is that because the `ProxyDict` only a has weak reference to the underlying container it's cleaned up before the second access of `._vgroups`, maybe there is a call to `__exit__` somewhere that's doing that. Fair point on `table`.  I don't usually call variables `stuff` either :-)